# Is there any way to get around a high waste outlet pipe?

Tags: drain-waste-vent, kitchen-sink

I've recently replaced my ancient sink with a new one, the taps don't leak it's sealed to the work top and looks great but the waste out let pipe was just below the old sink and the new one is a slightly deeper design.

As a result the water level in the piping is just below the plug fixture.  I have a second out let for the washing machine but it is in the corner of the room behind all the fixtures so would rather not have to use it.

---

This is my leaky setup at the moment

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three solutions.

## Raise the countertop

Increasing the height of the countertop, could give you enough height to install a proper drain.  Though I'm guessing you won't want to redo the cabinets and countertops.

## Modify the plumbing

Lowering the inlet in the wall would give you enough height for a proper drain, and is likely the most common solution.  It looks like that may not be an option i your case, as it looks like that might be a concrete wall.

## Install a basin pump

Drain the sinks into a basin, and then lift the waste water with a pump.  [SANIVITE®](http://www.saniflo.com/product-details-for-sanivite) makes the [SANIVITE®](http://www.saniflo.com/product-details-for-sanivite), which is designed for this type of install. I'm sure other companies offer similar products, so shop around to find one to meet your needs.

With this type of setup, you'll need a power source, and enough space to fit the basin.

---

Whatever you decide, the current plumbing definitely needs to go.  All the pipe that's below the throat of the wall inlet, will be full of water. That means the trap seal is likely too deep, which will lead to frequent clogging and slow draining.

[image]

> *I do not recommend nor endorse the use of any product mentioned here, all products are mentioned for example purposes only.*